# What is hmux in resin?

Tags: resin

When I start the Resin server it says

```
hmux listening to localhost:6802
```

What is this hmux? Is this a service or just resin use it for itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sample of Resin output:

```
Resin 3.0.2-beta (built Mon Aug  4 09:26:44 PDT 2003)
Copyright(c) 1998-2003 Caucho Technology.  All rights reserved.

Starting Resin on Mon, 04 Aug 2003 09:43:39 -0700 (PDT)
[09:43:40.664] Loaded Socket JNI library.
[09:43:40.664] http listening to *:8080
[09:43:40.664] ServletServer[] starting
[09:43:40.879] **hmux listening to *:6802**
[09:43:41.073] Host[] starting
[09:43:41.446] Application[http://localhost:8080/resin-doc] starting
[09:43:41.496] Application[http://localhost:8080] starting
```

Hmux port is the port which listen to Apache server.
- Web browser can call Resin directly via port 8080.
- Or web broswer can call Apache which in turn forward request to port hmux 6802 of resin

More information can be found at 
http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/install/cse-apache.xtp